# Select a Node which has specified subnodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have to write a web scraper. My php page is:

```
<a href="Something.php">
<div class="SPECIFIEDCLASS" title="other something">
</div>
</a>
```

What I wrote so far is:

```
var diiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/div[@class='SPECIFIEDCLASS']");

var hrefLiist = diiv.Select(q => q.GetAttributeValue("href", "not found")).ToList()
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression selects `div` tags with the specified class within `a` tags.
But what you want are the `a` tags with `div` tags with the specified class. You should instead use this XPath expression:

```
var diiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[div[@class='SPECIFIEDCLASS']]");
```

For a more visual explanation:

Your XPath does this to each `a` tag:

- Get `a` tag.
- Get child div tag.
- Select div tags with `Class = "SPECIFIEDCLASS"`. **So ultimately, the div tags are themselves selected**

The correct XPath should do this:

- Get `a` tag.
- Select `a` tags where:
  Child `div` tag has `Class = "SPECIFIEDCLASS"`. **Here the a tags are selected**.